# Information recording for Charging

Tags: onem2m

In TS-0001chapter 12 "Information Element Recording" triggers (e.g. a request on Mcc/Mca or any other interface) are described. 
In clause 12.2.2 "Filtering of Recorded Information for Offline Charging" it is described how to derive charging information from recorded information which means that charging data is being derived from IERs.

In clause 10.2.11.14, "Service Statistics collection record" is described.

There are 3 questions:

First, is there any correlation between `Service Statistics Collection record` and `IER`? It looks like Service statistics collection record is a subset of IER derived on the basis of `eventConfig` and `statsCollect` resources. If it is a subset, then there is no field in IER which maps to "collectingEntityID" as `Service Statistics Collection Record` are derived corresponding to "collectingEntityID".

Second, there is no description for charging data records (CDRs). It is described as subset of IER. As a result of `statsCollect`, `Service Statistics Collection Records` are generated. When will the CDRs be generated?

Third, there is no linking between `Service Statistics Collection record` and CDR, both needs to be transferred on Mch interface.

Answer (score 1):

For your first and third questions, I understand the confusion. The Service Statistics Collection record and a M2M Event Record probably should be combined or consolidated.  In fact, based on your question we will shortly bring in contributions to the oneM2M standard to make this change.

For the second question, TS-0001 clause 12.2.4 describes CDRs.  This clause defines Accounting-Request and Accounting-Answer messages that flow between an IN and a billing system over Mch.  Within the Accounting-Request there is an M2M Information element defined in which M2M Event Record information is stored. This is effectively the CDR. Depending on the requirements of the billing system, the charging function of the IN will filter the required information from the M2M Event Record and store this information in the M2M Information element of the Accounting-Request message for transfer to the billing system.

In addition, TS-0004 A.2 "Diameter Commands on Mch" defines how to bind the Mch Accounting-Request and Accounting-Answer messages to the Diameter protocol for deployments which use Diameter.